# Algorithm design for a simple "tour / intro" javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a tour for my web app.. It consists in multiple steps that are basically javascript functions

I thought of creating something like:

```
function step1(){
// show the first step text
// highlight a specific element or button
}

function step2{
// show the second step text
// highhlight a different button or area
}
```

Now these steps will be called on different actions, some will be when a button is clicked, some will be when something is hovered or maybe when the screen is clicked..

So I thought of creating an object called tourObj that holds an array of these functions and, when called,

```
tourObj.nextStep()
```

or

```
 gotoStep(x)
```

will go to next, back or to a specific part of the tutorial.

I came up with this solution but it kinda feels like there's a better way to do it. I'm sorry for the broad question but I'm a bit confused on how to build this, can someone point me a good way?

Comment: That is a reasonable approach. If your `step1`, `step2` functions are all doing the same thing (but with different text and buttons) then you should be able to replace them with a single function, which is passed a reference to the text and buttons to be shown/highlighted.

Comment: Have you already considered using something like http://introjs.com/?

Comment: They won't do the same thing @Stuart so I'll need different functions for them :/

Comment: I have considered using external libraries but I need a bit more customization.. so I decided to create my own

Comment: Better way to do what? Question is far too broad

Comment: You probably want to separate your "tour library" from the actual content in your specific tour.  So build an object that defines a trigger (button [id/class/data-?] click, hover, timeout, etc.), and the result (show this text, trigger this event, highlight this div...).  Then write your code to read in the tour "object", parse it and register all the events.  Then when you go to tour the next page, you're just writing another JSON object, not another set of functions.